# Python os.path.getsize

Tags: python

Копировал файлы из одной папки в другую. Чтобы фиксировать результат, хотел вычислять, размер файлов, которые уже скопировались на общий размер папки, из которой копировались. Но у меня возникла проблема, там всегда >100% получается - во много раз
Собственно беру я размер файла вот так

```
size_dir =float(os.path.getsize(pathdir))
size_file=float(os.path.getsize(pathfile)) #Примерно так, во float перевожу, чтобы удобнее считать было
```

Ну и у меня иногда получается, что размер файла уже больше чем размер папки, в котором находится файл. Почему? И как решить?

Comment: Потому что размер папки это отдельная величина, которая не имеет никакого отношения к размерам файлов

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392413/5741205